# JavaScript Validation Fail

Tags: javascript, html, validation

StackExchange community!
I have troubles with my HTML form validation. The below form is for a register page, found here:
http://cod5showtime.url.ph/register.html
The PHP part works perfectly, but the validation fails, for unknown reasons.

```
<form action="" method="post" name="reg" onSubmit="return validateForm()">
<div class="roundbox"><div class="grey">Register<br>Get a lot of advantages, only by making an account!<br><ul><li>Post Comments in Blog Posts;</li>
<li>Access the Members Area;</li>
<li>Enjoy Custom Titles and Other Features!</li></ul></div></div><br><br>     
            <label class="grey" for="username">Username:</label>        <br>
            <input class="field" type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" size="23" /><br><br>
            <label class="grey" for="email">Email:</label><br>
            <input class="field" type="text" name="email" id="email" size="23" /><br><br>
            <label class="grey" for="email">Password:</label><br>
            <input class="field" type="password" name="pass" id="pass" size="23" /><br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Account!" class="bt_register" /><br>
            <label class="grey">You will receive a e-mail with your password. Store it safely!</label>
            <div class="roundbox"><div class="grey" id="error"></div>
            <div class="grey" id="error2"></div>
            <div class="grey" id="error3"></div></div>
</form>
```

The form works well as I said. I will explain below how it works as it's quite hard to understand my code [in my opinion].

```
id = "error" div is for username errors
id = "error2" div is for password errors
id = "error3" div is for email errors (not scripted in JS yet!)
```

And this is my JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm()
{
var user=document.forms["reg"]["username"].value;
var pass=document.forms["reg"]["pass"].value;
if (user.length < 4 || user.length > 32) 
  {
document.getElementById("error").innerHTML="Invalid username specified:<br>Choose a username of 3 to 32 characters!";
  return false;
  }
    if (user == NULL || user == '') 
  {
document.getElementById("error").innerHTML="No username specified!";
  return false;
  }
if (pass.length < 4 || pass.length > 32) 
  {
document.getElementById("error2").innerHTML="Invalid password specified:<br>For safety reasons passwords have to be 3 to 32 characters long!";
  return false;
  }
if (pass == NULL || pass == '') 
  {
document.getElementById("error2").innerHTML="No password specified!";
      return false;
  }
}
</script>
```

If you'd be kind enough to check the page I gave you, you'll see the username validation works, but password doesn't.

Comment: There's no NULL in Javascript. There's `null`

Comment: Even the user validation does not work, it throws JS errors as you might see in firebug: "`... NULL is not defined ...`". See @lukas comment: it should be `null` instead.

Comment: WOW! I just had to change the NULL to 'null' and the validation works now. Thank you a lot! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the form is posting once it passes the first validation before it ever tries to validate the other fields.

Once a valid username is entered the form is posted and the email address + password validation is skipped.

Try putting it all within the same if statement so all criteria must be met before the form is posted.

I recommend installing a debugging tool such as firebug which helped identify this promptly.

You might also want to research existing regex methods for validating email addresses as I suspect there are some good methods out there on the net.